# Combine multiple sql tables and multiple sql queries into one statement

Tags: php, mysql

I have done research on using the join method, to join tables together, but I not only want to join tables, but also queries into one statement and I do not know how to join queries together into one.

I have three tables, one called friends, one called users and one called beers.

user table:

name | id

friends table:

userID | friendName

beer table:

userID | beer

I want to find all the friends for a given user, and query get a count of the unique beers each user and there friends have.

Previously I was using php to  "build" sql statements to execute and this was making lots of sql calls in loops and was just messy. I know there has to be a more efficient way of doing this.

Comment: Do friends have their on id or just names associated with userid?

Comment: in the friends table just their names, I need their id from the user table to get their beer count from the beer table, as it only has their id's

Comment: Well then you need a way to associate friends to a user, because right now you don't have that in your schema

Comment: if I add friend id to the friend table would I be good?

Comment: Are friends also users?

Comment: yes friends are in the user table as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f1fdd/9

Build schema:

```sql
CREATE TABLE user(
  id int(11),
  name varchar(50)
);
CREATE TABLE userFriends(
  userID int(11),
  friendID int(11)
);
CREATE TABLE beer(
  beerID int(11),
  beerName varchar(50)
);
CREATE TABLE friendBeer(
  userID int(11),
  beerID int(11)
);
INSERT INTO user(id,name) VALUES(1,'friend 1');
INSERT INTO user(id,name) VALUES(2,'friend 2');
INSERT INTO user(id,name) VALUES(3,'friend 3');
INSERT INTO user(id,name) VALUES(4,'jeremy');

INSERT INTO userFriends(userID,friendID) VALUES(4,1);
INSERT INTO userFriends(userID,friendID) VALUES(4,2);
INSERT INTO userFriends(userID,friendID) VALUES(4,3);

INSERT INTO beer(beerID, beerName) VALUES(1, 'amstel light');
INSERT INTO beer(beerID, beerName) VALUES(2, 'bud light');
INSERT INTO beer(beerID, beerName) VALUES(3, 'miller');

INSERT INTO friendBeer(userID, beerID) VALUES(1, 1);
INSERT INTO friendBeer(userID, beerID) VALUES(2, 2);
INSERT INTO friendBeer(userID, beerID) VALUES(3, 3);
INSERT INTO friendBeer(userID, beerID) VALUES(4, 1);
INSERT INTO friendBeer(userID, beerID) VALUES(1, 3);
```

And the query:

```sql
SELECT U.id,
       U.name,
       (SELECT count(beerID)
        FROM friendBeer 
        WHERE userID = 4) AS "user beer count",
       U2.name AS 'Friends name',
       COUNT(FB2.beerID)
FROM user U
LEFT JOIN userFriends F
  ON U.id = F.userID
LEFT JOIN user U2
  ON F.friendID = U2.id
LEFT JOIN friendBeer FB2
  ON F.friendID = FB2.userID
LEFT JOIN friendBeer FB
  ON U.id = FB.userID
WHERE U.id = 4
GROUP BY F.friendID, U.id
```

I'm assuming you will change `=1` to whatever the `UserID` is - but this shows you how the query works.

Comment: awesome that helps, but it doesn't look like it includes the user whos friends I am checking for.

Comment: @Evan Please learn [how to format code in your posts](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: @peterm ... it was just a rushing mistake ... but thanks for the link

Comment: I am not getting the results I want. I want the total beers for each user. I am getting the same number for each user.

Comment: Define "user" then ... because we're only pulling results for one user (from the user table) in that query.

Comment: Did you want the beer count for each `friend` instead?

Comment: Yea, I want the count for each friend and the count for the user.

Comment: Well then you'll need to change the way your tables are setup because there is no way to link an individual friend to a beer.

Comment: @Mike Your tables structure doesn't support that. Your friend and beers associated only with user

Comment: @Mike Let me know if the new update does the trick - I think it's what you're looking for.

Comment: @Evan that is almost perfect. It gets the total beers for all a given users friends. Is there also a way to get the users count in there also, along with his friends?

Comment: @Mike Actually, what do you mean by their "count"? How many there are? If so, just realize the same number will come back for each row since each row represents the same user

Comment: SO right now its returns my friends total beer counts. I also want to return my total beer count along with my friends.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26795/discussion-between-evan-and-mike)

Answer (score 0):

```
create table user(user_id int(11),user_name varchar(100));
create table friend(user_id int(11),friend_to int(11));
create table beer(user_id int(11),beer_name varchar(100));

insert into user values(1,'Evan');
insert into user values(2,'Mike');
insert into user values(3,'Roxetta');
insert into user values(4,'Rajesh');

insert into friend values(1,2);
insert into friend values(1,3);

insert into beer values(1,'sam bud');
insert into beer values(2,'carlsberg');
insert into beer values(2,'sam bud');
insert into beer values(2,'sam bud');
```

and the sql query

```
SELECT user.user_name, COUNT(DISTINCT(beer.beer_name)) `count` FROM beer JOIN `user` ON user.user_id=beer.user_id WHERE user.user_id=1
UNION
SELECT user.user_name,COUNT(DISTINCT(beer.beer_name)) FROM beer JOIN `user` ON user.user_id=beer.user_id 
WHERE user.user_id IN(SELECT friend_to FROM friend WHERE user_id=1);
```

Is this what you looking for?